# Cumulative Sum Query in SQL table with distinct elements

Tags: sql, cumulative-sum, distinct-values

I have a table like this, with column names as **Date of Sale** and insurance **Salesman Names** -

```
Date of Sale | Salesman Name | Sale Amount
2021-03-01   | Jack          | 40  
2021-03-02   | Mark          | 60
2021-03-03   | Sam           | 30 
2021-03-03   | Mark          | 70 
2021-03-02   | Sam           | 100
```

I want to do a group by, using the date of sale. The next column should display the cumulative count of the sellers who have made the sale till that date. But same sellers shouldn't be considered again.

For example,
The following table is incorrect,

```
Date of Sale | Count(Salesman Name) | Sum(Sale Amount)
2021-03-01   | 1                    | 40
2021-03-02   | 3                    | 200
2021-03-03   | 5                    | 300
```

The following table is correct,

```
Date of Sale | Count(Salesman Name) | Sum(Sale Amount)
2021-03-01   | 1                    | 40
2021-03-02   | 3                    | 200
2021-03-03   | 3                    | 300
```

I am not sure how to frame the SQL query, because there are two conditions involved here, cumulative count while ignoring the duplicates. I think the OVER clause along with the unbounded row preceding may be of some use here? Request your help

Edit - I have added the Sale Amount as a column. I need the cumulative sum for the Sales Amount also. But in this case , all the sale amounts should be considered unlike the salesman name case where only unique names were being considered.

Comment: Please specify the dbms your are using. Different vendors support different features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses a self join and aggregation:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.SaleDate,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.Salesman IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS cnt,
           SUM(t1.SaleAmount) AS amt
    FROM yourTable t1
    LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t2.Salesman = t1.Saleman AND
           t2.SaleDate < t1.SaleDate
    GROUP BY t1.SaleDate
)

SELECT
    SaleDate,
    SUM(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY SaleDate) AS NumSalesman,
    SUM(amt) OVER (ORDER BY SaleDate) AS TotalAmount
FROM cte
ORDER BY SaleDate;
```

The logic in the CTE is that we try to find, for each salesman, an earlier record for the same salesman.  If we *can't* find such a record, then we assume the record in question is the first appearance.  Then we aggregate by date to get the counts per day, and finally take a rolling sum of counts in the outer query.

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for the answer. I have added one more column in my table. Can you suggest the changes that are required to be made in your query, for incorporating the sales amount column

Comment: Hey, will this ignore duplicate salesman names , while not ignoring the any sales amount rows?

Comment: Sure, will accept the answer, once the issue is resolved

Comment: Will amounts such as 70 and 100, in my table not be ignored?

Comment: You should first try my updated answer and then ask questions about it afterwards.

Comment: Hi Tim,It's  not working . Results only up to 2nd march are getting displayed

Comment: I have added a screenshot in your answer, please check . I have written the same query as you

Comment: Hey, I would like to suggest a minor edit. This line is giving the wrong output -> SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Salesman IS NULL THEN t1.SaleAmount ELSE 0 END) AS amt. Can we replace it by using simply SUM(t1.SaleAmount)?

Comment: The final output is wrong - For 3rd March, the output I'm getting is 200, while in reality it should be 300

Comment: You're right...I think you just want the unconditional sum of the sales amount.

Comment: Yes, so is the change I've suggested fine? Or is there something else required? Request you to please update your answer accordingly

Comment: Hey Tim, what if a single date can have multiple occurrences of the same name, how to eliminate that?

Comment: The query fails in case a single date can have multiple occurrences of the same name

Comment: I don't know what to say, because I can't see this new data.  I suggest that you open a new question at this point.  Please _do not_ edit your question again.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask a new question. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: Just show clear data along with what output you want.  This avoids having to follow up so many times.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67355357/find-cumulative-sum-of-insurance-sales-amount-with-increasing-date-while-conside

Comment: Hi Tim. Can you help me out with my new question?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this uses window functions to determine the first time a sales person appears.  Then, you just want cumulative sums:

```
select saledate,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by saledate) as num_salespersons,
       sum(sum(sales)) over (order by saledate) as running_sales
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by salesperson order by saledate) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by saledate
order by saledate;
```

Note that this in addition to being more concise, this should have much, much better performance than a solution that uses a self-join.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this answer Gordon. Provides a completely new way of solving a complex query. Any good resources for learning about window functions?

Comment: I would suggest that you start with the documentation for the database you are using.